# nextjs ssr local font

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using SSR with Next.js to receive HTML from the server and display it, but the default font is displayed on the first screen, and then the custom font is applied. How can I improve this?

**_app.tsx**

```
const myFont = localFont({
  src: \[
      { path: 'Pretendard-Regular.woff2', weight: '400', style: 'normal' },
      {
        path: 'Pretendard-Medium.woff2',
        weight: '500',
        style: 'normal',
      },
      {
        path: 'Pretendard-SemiBold.woff2',
        weight: '600',
        style: 'normal',
      },
      {
        path: 'Pretendard-Black.woff2',
        weight: '900',
        style: 'normal',
      },
  \],
  display: 'swap',
    preload: true,
  });
  
return (
  <style jsx global>
    {`
      html {
        font-family: ${myFont.style.fontFamily};
      }
    `}
  </style>
)

<div className = { myFont.className } >
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</div>
```

I have written the code like this now.
server: nginx
node: 18.15.0
pnpm: 7.29.3

I would like the screen to show the locally applied font from the beginning without displaying the default font first and then switching to the local font.